# Read json line by line using generator

Tags: python, json, generator

I have a `json` file which is pretty big, and a function which reads the `json` file.

I need to keep the state between function calls (the next time when the function will be called I do not need to read the json file from the first line instead I need the function to pick up from where it had remained), so the first thing that came into my mind was the generator protocol.

This is my first attempt, but the function behaviour is not the desired one:

```py
def first_task(file_name):
    """"
    Read file_name line by line
    """
    import json
    data = []
    with open(file_name) as f: 
        for line in f:
            try:
                data.append(json.loads(line))
            except ValueError:  # includes simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError
                print ('Decoding JSON has failed')
    yield data
```

What I would like is when `first_task("test.json")` it's called for the **first time** to return the **first line** from the json, then when the function is called **second time** to return the **second line** from json, and so on until the EOF is reached.

Sample from `json` file:

```
{"venue":{"venue_name":"Datong High School","lon":0,"lat":0,"venue_id":23779799},"visibility":"public","response":"no","guests":0,"member":{"member_id":120119272,"photo":"http:\/\/photos3.meetupstatic.com\/photos\/member\/b\/2\/b\/c\/thumb_262125756.jpeg","member_name":"Allen Wang"},"rsvp_id":1658733801,"mtime":1489925470960,"event":{"event_name":"Play Intermediate Volleyball","event_id":"jkpwmlywgbmb","time":1491613200000,"event_url":"https:\/\/www.meetup.com\/Taipei-Sports-and-Social-Club\/events\/236786445\/"},"group":{"group_topics":[{"urlkey":"fitness","topic_name":"Fitness"},{"urlkey":"mountain-biking","topic_name":"Mountain Biking"},{"urlkey":"sports","topic_name":"Sports and Recreation"},{"urlkey":"outdoors","topic_name":"Outdoors"},{"urlkey":"fun-times","topic_name":"Fun Times"},{"urlkey":"winter-and-summer-sports","topic_name":"Winter and Summer Sports"},{"urlkey":"adventure","topic_name":"Adventure"},{"urlkey":"water-sports","topic_name":"Water Sports"},{"urlkey":"sports-and-socials","topic_name":"Sports and Socials"},{"urlkey":"hiking","topic_name":"Hiking"},{"urlkey":"excercise","topic_name":"Exercise"},{"urlkey":"recreational-sports","topic_name":"Recreational Sports"}],"group_city":"Taipei","group_country":"tw","group_id":16585312,"group_name":"Taipei Sports and Social Club","group_lon":121.45,"group_urlname":"Taipei-Sports-and-Social-Club","group_lat":25.02}}
{"venue":{"venue_name":"Cafe Vitus","lon":121.54731,"lat":25.052959,"venue_id":19712922},"visibility":"public","response":"no","guests":0,"member":{"member_id":221379606,"photo":"http:\/\/photos2.meetupstatic.com\/photos\/member\/8\/3\/c\/4\/thumb_263973732.jpeg","member_name":"Benita  Syu"},"rsvp_id":1658877353,"mtime":1489925471668,"event":{"event_name":"New Place! Every Saturday night multilingual café","event_id":"hvkmsmywfbhc","time":1490439600000,"event_url":"https:\/\/www.meetup.com\/polyglottw\/events\/238185973\/"},"group":{"group_topics":[{"urlkey":"language","topic_name":"Language & Culture"},{"urlkey":"language-exchange","topic_name":"Language Exchange"},{"urlkey":"chinese-language","topic_name":"Chinese Language"}],"group_city":"Taipei","group_country":"tw","group_id":18743595,"group_name":"Multilingual Cafe Language Exchange","group_lon":121.45,"group_urlname":"polyglottw","group_lat":25.02}}
{"venue":{"venue_name":"Panera Bread","lon":0,"lat":0,"venue_id":24945082},"visibility":"public","response":"yes","guests":0,"member":{"member_id":44748032,"photo":"http:\/\/photos4.meetupstatic.com\/photos\/member\/d\/7\/1\/6\/thumb_64255062.jpeg","member_name":"Valerie"},"rsvp_id":1658877355,"mtime":1489925472035,"event":{"event_name":"Meet & Greet Icebreaker conversations in Morris County","event_id":"236222256","time":1490389200000,"event_url":"https:\/\/www.meetup.com\/Mingle-Around-In-North-Jersey-Single-Events-Adventures\/events\/236222256\/"},"group":{"group_topics":[{"urlkey":"wine","topic_name":"Wine"},{"urlkey":"hiking","topic_name":"Hiking"},{"urlkey":"diningout","topic_name":"Dining Out"},{"urlkey":"marketing","topic_name":"Marketing"},{"urlkey":"newintown","topic_name":"New In Town"},{"urlkey":"socialnetwork","topic_name":"Social Networking"},{"urlkey":"women","topic_name":"Women's Social"},{"urlkey":"outdoors","topic_name":"Outdoors"},{"urlkey":"professional-networking","topic_name":"Professional Networking"},{"urlkey":"adventure","topic_name":"Adventure"},{"urlkey":"singles-30s-50s","topic_name":"Singles 30's-50's"},{"urlkey":"small-business-marketing-strategy","topic_name":"Small Business Marketing Strategy"},{"urlkey":"professional-singles","topic_name":"Single Professionals"},{"urlkey":"dating-and-relationships","topic_name":"Dating and Relationships"},{"urlkey":"singles-40s-50s","topic_name":"Singles 40's - 50's"}],"group_city":"Hackensack","group_country":"us","group_id":17370312,"group_name":"Mingle Around 30s 40s 50s (Single Events & Adventures)","group_lon":-74.05,"group_urlname":"Mingle-Around-In-North-Jersey-Single-Events-Adventures","group_state":"NJ","group_lat":40.89}}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the JSON is formatted properly to accommodate this?

Comment: I added the first lines from the json file, the `data` list seems to be constructed correctly in the sense that it's a list of dict objects. I do not know if the generator approach is the best one, but I want to avoid reading all the json file each time the `first_task` function it's called.

Comment: You could keep some sort of counter, right? _I want to avoid reading all the json file each time the first_task function it's called._ Can you be a bit more specific? If you call the function each time, you will be starting over.

Comment: Looking at the accepted solution, why not just read the entire file into a list of lines? The effect will be the same, you haven't presented anything which might indicate that your program needs something particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. With no error checking.

```
def gen(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fh:
        line = fh.readline()
        while line:
            yield json.loads(line)
            line = fh.readline()
```

In python 3.8 you could do it like this:

```
def gen(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fh:
        while line := fh.readline():
            yield json.loads(line)
```

Comment: Does using `readline()` procure some advantage over looping on `fh` directly?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not quite clear on what you need,  if you just need individual lines, instead of constructing a list you can just yield each line and then call the generator with `next` as you need it, since this will only the read the file once and supply individual lines as needed until it is exhausted:

```
## contents of example.txt

{"first": "line"}
{"second": "line"}
{"third": "line"}
```

Construction of line supplier:

```
def supply_line(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            yield json.loads(line)
```

When you call it with [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#next) ensure to provide a default, so you don't have wrap around a `try/except` to catch a `StopIteration` exception:

`producer = supply_line('file_with_json_lines.txt')`

```
In [7]: next(producer, '')
Out[7]: {'first': 'line'}

In [8]: next(producer, '')
Out[8]: {'second': 'line'}

In [9]: next(producer, '')
Out[9]: {'third': 'line'}

## when the file is done, it will produce a default, which in this case is an empty string
In [10]: next(producer, '')
Out[10]: ''

In [11]: next(producer, '')
Out[11]: ''
```

If you need to start over, you can call the generator again, if you want to store all the lines in a list, you can cast the generator to list (*however this will load the file everytime*):

```
In [13]: all_lines = list(supply_line('file_with_json_lines.txt'))

In [14]: all_lines
Out[14]: [{'first': 'line'}, {'second': 'line'}, {'third': 'line'}]
```

And obviously a `for` loop:

```
In [15]: for line in supply_line('file_with_json_lines.txt'):
    ...:     print(line)
    ...:
{'first': 'line'}
{'second': 'line'}
{'third': 'line'}
```